# How to remove only simple product not configurable and virtual product from collection when price is zero

Tags: magento2, database

di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection">
        <plugin name="beforeproductCollectionPlugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CollectionPlugin" />
    </type>
```

CollectionPlugin.php

```
class CollectionPlugin
{
    /**
     * Remove product which price is less than one.
     *
     * @param Collection $subject
     * @param bool $printQuery
     * @param bool $logQuery
     */
    public function beforeLoad(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $subject,
        $printQuery = false,
        $logQuery = false
    ) {
        if (!$subject->isLoaded()) {
            $subject->addAttributeToFilter([['attribute' => 'type_id','in' => 'configurable,virtual'],['attribute' => 'price','gt' => 0]]);
        }
        return $subject;
    }
}
```

I have added this result hide all product whose price is less than or equal to zero but I need condition apply for only on simple product.

Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to refactor your call to `addAttributeToFilter`.

```php
$subject->addAttributeToSelect('price')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', ['in' => ['configurable','virtual']])
    ->addAttributeToFilter('price', ['gt' => 0]);
```

Also, you should be aware that this plugin will filter every product collection with this logic - is that desired?

Comment: Thanks for your help , I will try